# ASP.NET WebApi modelbinding to a complex type containing DateTime

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This question regards ASP.NET WebApi in MVC 4, not ASP.NET MVC.

Consider the following WebApi Model

```
  public class MyComplex 
  {
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
  }
```

bound by model binding as parameter to the following ApiController method

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostMyComplex(MyComplex id){ .. }
}
```

How do I declare what format the model binder should expect for MyComplex.Date? As I see it, Modelbinders in WebApi does the trick when the parameter is of type DateTime itself, but I haven't seen a good way of handling date formats when they are part of a complex type and I want to restrict what is acceptable for the api. I have gone down the route of experimenting with both Modelbinders and ValueProviders, none of which seems suitable.

I want to explicitly restrict acceptable HttpPosts on format dd-MM-yyyy.

Comment: Which content types are you supporting. Json, Xml, Form-url-encoded... all of the above? Each content type is going to require a different approach.

Comment: Json and XML should both be supported, as pr out of the box functionality with WebApi. About the different approaches of supporting each case. Are you thinking of [FromUrl], [FromBody] and [ModelBinder(typeof(MySpecificModelBinder)] ?

Comment: Well asuming you are posting MyComplex within the body... then WebApi wont use ModelBinders it will instead use MediaTypeFormaters. For Json it will use the JSON media type formatter and for xml the Xml media type formatter. To customise the deserialisation and validation of the model you need to look at JSON.net settings and the data contract settings for XML.

Comment: Seems as though it would be easier to make the MyComplex.Date of type string, and parse that to a DateTime myself serverside.